# How can I write a sql query to list names from a table which are starting and ending with the same character?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried using the like and regular expressions but the result is not meeting my needs.

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT Name FROM People WHERE LEFT(Name,1)= RIGHT(Name,1);
```